# Missing a backtick from Markdown table in preview was well rendered, but not server side

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview, tables

[image]

Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1464175/93706

In the table below, `1{print}` is missing its closing backtick. The preview handles this well by having it render as plain text instead of code but when posted, the table fails completely.

To test, click **edit**. Preview will be well rendered:

|  Operator | Meaning |
| ----------- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| `{}` | awk operation/expression/code |
| `count` | a random variable |
| `+=1`   | +1 increment |
| `END` or `true contition` | code to run... at the `END` or on `true condition`. `awk` is all about `true{expr}` like `1{print} | |` count/NR`| simple arithmetic division | |`NR`| number of the current/last line:`N`umber of` R`ecords |

> [image: Screenshot of table in edit preview. The relevant item is circled with a red freehand circle to make it stand out better]

Comment: I suggest to use `ezgif.com` to convert video to GIF and upload as image directly into question body.

Comment: 'Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server' size of gif is 20k

Comment: 20k? imgur for SE support the image less 2Mb.

Comment: https://ezgif.com/resize/ezgif-5-41fcab5df7.gif

Comment: Your file is 25.28MiB, you need to reduce the size more than 10 time to fit into 2MiB. First of all I think it's better to crop the area to eliminate not relevant part of grabbed screen.

Comment: licecap's a really good tool on windows and OS X for video screenshots. Its not *perfect* but I loaded your video into a quarter of a 1080p and captured it, size is a lot better.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is licecap able to convert video from file? O_o

Comment: @αλεχολυτ actually, I really can't see any added value in showing it either as video or a gif. Reproducing is as easy here as clicking the edit link and seeing the preview.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard main value that the post become not dependent on external resources. Without animation you won't be able to understand the issue when it will be fixed.

Comment: nope, but I can capture the youtube video

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There is zero reason for gif here. It's just annoying noise. (Like almost everywhere.) You have worsened the post.